# How can I display sales tax in order confirmation email

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, ecommerce, email, order-info

I am trying to display sales tax in the order confirmation email but it does not appear to be available. Can I add my own variables that I want to make available in the email? If so, how and where would I do that?

thanks!

**Update specifics**

ah, well.. I thought that this **was** the support forum for the actual module but wasn't paying attention that it only said ExpressionEngine and not the actual module.

Anyway EE  **v2.4.0 - Build: date  20120123** and it is the **Store** module by **Exp-resso 1.5.3**

Comment: Hi and welcome Kelvin, can you let us know what EE addon you're using?

Comment: More details are needed. What add-on are you using? What version of EE and what version of that addon?

Comment: Kevin - I'm guessing you came here from the Exp:resso Store support page? This site is a Q&A site for ExpressionEngine development generally, which includes *all* add-ons. So if your question is about a specific add-on, you need to be clear about that.

Comment: Clearly we need to improve our communication on that page. Will review it today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have said in the comments you should as as much information as possible about your setup so that we can provide accurate results.

**Exp:resso Store**
If you are using [Exp:resso Store](https://exp-resso.com/store/) there are a few options you can use. To display item specific sales tax you would want to use `item_tax` tag inside of the items loop

```
{items}
 Item Tax = {item_tax}
{/items}
```

If  you want to display the tax for the entire order there are a couple tags you can use as mentioned in the [docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/tags/checkout.html#order-details)

```
{order_subtotal_tax} = All the tax that is applicable to the orders subtotal
{order_shipping_tax} = The tax that is applicable to the shipping cost
{order_tax} = All the tax applicable to the entire order (includes subtotal and shipping)
```

You can also display the tax information such as name and rate with the followingL

```
{tax_name} = Value for the tax rate based upon your settings in the CP
{tax_rate} = Value like "0.10"
{tax_percentage} = Value like "10%"
```

**CartThrob**
If you are using [CartThrob](http://cartthrob.com) you would need to add the custom fields that you assigned to store tax, subtotal plus tax, shipping plus tax fields depending on what you want.

**BrilliantRetail**
If you are using [BrilliantRetail](http://brilliantretail.com) you would want to use something like [this](http://docs.brilliantretail.com/developers/template-tags/checkout/checkout-thank-you.html) I haven't used BR in a really long time so I am not 100% sure of their tag structure but looking through the included templates should help.

Comment: Hey great answer. I have updated my question. I just assumed the tags specified in the admin were the only tags available. Thanks again.

Comment: The ones in the admin are just a few of the tags available you can use most Store tags without a problem. Glad that you got it sorted out now.